# Subscribe to multiple observables and emit value when each is completed

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, fork-join, combinelatest

On my

`ngOnInit()`

I have this code:

`combineLatest([ obs1, obs2, obs3]).subscribe(([obs1Res, Obs2Res, Obs3Res]) => { })`

and the result is emitted once when they are completed.

Is there a way to emit for each new completed observable and get a result like so:

```
[null, 2, null], [1, 2, null], [1, 2, 3]
```

I will use this to dynamically render a page and assign the values if they are not null.

```
combineLatest([obs1, obs2, obs3]).subscribe(([obs1Res, Obs2Res, Obs3Res]) => {firstValue ??= Obs1Res; secondValue ??= Obs2Res; thirdValue ??= Obs3Res })
```

Comment: `zip` is what you want !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and the result is emitted once when they are completed

With `combineLatest` the first emission will occur after each source emits at least one value.  Then, after that an emission with occur when any of the sources emit.

If your goal is to receive `null` for those that haven't emitted yet, you an use `startWith` to provide an initial emission for each source:

```js
combineLatest([ 
  obs1.pipe(startWith(null)), 
  obs2.pipe(startWith(null)), 
  obs3.pipe(startWith(null)),
]).subscribe(
  ([obs1Res, Obs2Res, Obs3Res]) => { }
);
```

This will provide you with *almost* the output you desire:

```json
[null, null, null], [null, 2, null], [1, 2, null], [1, 2, 3]
```

To prevent the initial `[null, null, null]` emission, you can use `skip`:

```js
combineLatest([ 
  obs1.pipe(startWith(null)), 
  obs2.pipe(startWith(null)), 
  obs3.pipe(startWith(null)),
]).pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(
  ([obs1Res, Obs2Res, Obs3Res]) => { }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

combineLastest will combine all the latest values for any emit from any of the observables. if you want all the latest from all the observables then you can use `zip()`.

There could be a different solution for what you want. Use this visual representation for what you want from your subscription: https://rxmarbles.com/

Comment: I tried zip, but it emits only once - when they all of obs. are completed.